# SVG support on magnolia-cms

Tags: svg, magnolia, dam

I am having some trouble with vector images in magnolia.

Not everywhere, but images that go through the imaging module, don't give a result.

This makes sense to me as resizing / optimizing is what this module does and that wouldn't be applicable to a vector (e.g. *.svg)

Is there a way I can configure the imaging module to 'just give back the image' if it's an SVG image?

All documentation seems to point to:

```
NoOpAssetRenderer

The module magnolia-dam-core provides  NoOpAssetRenderer which can be used to define 
global AssetRenderer. Per default, NoOpAssetRenderer does only wrap the original Asset.
```

But I can't figure out how to configure this.

Concrete example, my thumbnails during asset selection give me:

[image]

The url for such an image would be
`<base-url>/.imaging/thumbnail/dam/<asset-name>.svg`

Is there anyone who has made this work?